# Different subnets for Virtual machine & host?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

If I configure my VM to be in a different subnet from the host, Is there any way to make the host reachable from the VM?

I do not expect the host to handle the packets, I just want to know whether in that scenario, is there any way to make the packets from my VM reach my host?

Setup:
CentOS 6.5 VM running on top of a Windows 7 host in Oracle VirtualBox.

I just tried the following scenario:

1. Assign static IP from different subnet to my VM's bridged network adapter.
2. Ping the first address of that subnet from VM.

The ping reaches my Windows host.(checked on wireshark).
But *no* other ping reaches my Windows host.
Is there some workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input I would propose something like that:

```
┌──────┐            ┌────────┐            ┌────────┐ 
│ HOST ├── VMnet0 ──┤ GUEST1 ├── VMnet1 ──┤ GUEST2 │
└──────┘            └────────┘            └────────┘
```

`GUEST1` can have any access to Internet through VMnet0, for example Bridged / Host-only / NAT. But I prefer Host-only as both `HOST` and `GUEST1` see each other (have different IPs) and it is much more efficient than Bridged. Host-only can be also bridged with any network interface using Windows Bridge mechanism.

You can provide Internet using ICS, but you have to switch off default built-in DHCP server of VMnet Host-only. You can switch it off using following commands:

```
VBoxManage.exe list dhcpservers
VBoxManage.exe dhcpserver remove --netname "HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"
```

`GUEST2` gets access to Internet through VMnet1 routed by `GUEST1`. I think it should be Host-only with DHCP switched off.

Comment: how about telling him  whether it just works automatically, or whether there is a special setting. suppose for example it's virtualbox. By the way, are they really your eyebrows or is that photoshopped or stick ons, or not you?

Comment: @Virus_7 - I am looking into scenario where my host & VM are in different subnets, & then experiment a bit around software routing...

Comment: @AshishKulkarni The key is Host-only Adapter.

Comment: @barlop It's some down light. No Photoshop here. ;)